# Unix: Replace line with string in another file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, replace

**File1.txt**

```
1.1.1.1
```

**File2.txt**

```
tcp=ipv4
netmask=255.255.255.0
ip=
```

**Desired Output:**

```
tcp=ipv4
netmask=255.255.255.0
ip=1.1.1.1
```

I want to replace complete line in **File2.txt** from **File1.txt** value searching by **"ip="** string.

i try:

```
sed '/ip=/r File1.txt' File2.txt | sed '/ip=/d'
```

**Output:**

```
tcp=ipv4
netmask=255.255.255.0
1.1.1.1
```

How to add "ip=" string value to get desired output?

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: sed '/ip/r File1.txt' File2.txt

Comment: `sed '/ip/r File1.txt' File2.txt | sed '/^ip=/{N; s/\n//}'`?

Comment: sed: 1: "/^ip=/{N; s/\n//}": bad flag in substitute command: '}'

Comment: @DarvinRiveraAguilar, Changing questions later on is NOT encouraged on SO, so please revert it to your actual question else it will make no sense for all given answers to future users, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. This will handle multiple occurrence/values in file1.txt and fil2.txt too.

```
awk -F'=' '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="=" }
FNR==NR{
  arr[++count]=$0
  next
}
/^ip/{
  print $1 OFS arr[++count1]
  next
}
1' file1.txt file2.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk  '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="=" }
FNR==NR{                   ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file1.txt is being read.
  arr[++count]=$0          ##Creating arr with index of increasing value of count and its value is current line.
  next                     ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
/^ip/{                     ##Checking condition if line starts from ip then do following.
  print $1 OFS arr[++count1]   ##Printing current line and arr with index of increasing value of count1.
  next                     ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
1                          ##1 will print all lines here.
' file1.txt file2.txt      ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: What happens if i have separate by space in file2.txt , for example: ip 8.8.8.8?

Comment: @DarvinRiveraAguilar, you need to change delimiter then to FS=OFS="\t"  cheers

Comment: with \t add File1.txt line at end ip 8.8.8.8 of File2.txt: ip 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
I need replace always last ip value in File2.txt

Comment: @DarvinRiveraAguilar, Please revert your question to your actual one, for changing from `ip   file1_value` to `ip  file2_value` change `-F'=' ` TO `-F'\t' ` and that should do the trick then.

Answer (score 2):

```
IP=`cat File1.txt`
sed "/^ip=$/s/$/$IP/" File2.txt
```